# Do colors change with file size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I work with multiple brands, creating eDMs, flyers and posters.
To be able to maintain Brand Integrity across all my media, I need to often refer to the CMYK or RGB charts given in each brand's color guidelines.

Instead of creating individual swatches to import once I start a project, I was thinking I could create vector squares of the color palette, and export it as a medium-quality PNG to import into Ai for me to use the color-dropper on elements that then require these brand colors.

What I haven't been able to find out online, is if I do this, will the colors change if I eye-drop from a PNG?

Bear in mind that this is all before printing/exporting into JPEG or PDF.

Answer (score 4):

Do not do that.

> I need to often refer to the CMYK or RGB charts

PNG does not support CMYK

> will the colors change if I eye-drop from a PNG?

RGB colors on a PNG file can change if you are using the color profile embedded or not.

---

Probably a better method is to prepare custom palettes and swatches palettes to import, or to prepare a base template with those included.

But if you were willing to import a PNG file, why don't you prepare a nice Illustrator graphic with the necessary info and import it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically when I develop branding for a client or entity, I develop a style guide, and inside that style guide one page is specifically just a brand colour guide - this has an array of vector squares with the relevant colour as a fill, and directly beneath it, as text, the associated RGB, Hex, CMYK and LAB values for other designers to correctly reference in future projects.

As well as examples of all graphics being in the style guide as native vectors, I also save separate Graphic Style libraries, Text Style libraries, any Pattern Swatches as libraries, and all colour swatches as libraries. I also save out pre-canned Symbols and Assets for all such developed branding content. I use Affinity Designer, Photo (and now Publisher) as well as Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign, and occasionally Sketch App (wireframing and UI) so I go through the due diligence to save out these standardisation tools in all relevant formats which might apply for that given client and use case.

For myself I would never save as png and eyedropper... way too many chances for minor interpolation errors - go vector, save swatches, re-use these.